# 'with people of diverse backgrounds and areas of expertise'

Tags: prepositions

In the sentence fragment

> with people of diverse backgrounds and areas of expertise

is the usage of prepositions okay? Since I wouldn't say 'People OF diverse areas of expertise' but 'People WITH diverse areas of expertise', I feel like the fragment might have to be

> with people of diverse backgrounds and with diverse areas of expertise

but that would be rather inelegant since both 'with' and 'diverse' would be duplicated.

Comment: *Of* is fine for both.  *With* is probably more standard, but *of diverse X* is a common enough affectation that no one would notice.

Comment: You can avoid the quandary by using *having*; *"... people having diverse backgrounds and areas of expertise."*

Comment: with people of diverse backgrounds and areas of expertise. There is no need to repeat the of. The people of New York and Boston.